# Kivy - Label not updating on UI

Tags: python, kivy

When I click on the buttons in the left part, the label "Top 10 Plays of 2015" should be changed with the text of the button that I've clicked. I can see the variable changing text but the label is not changing text.

this is my work: when I click the buttons on left side the title in the middle should change:
[image: screen shot]

python

```
class MainApp(Screen, EventDispatcher):
    vid = StringProperty("Videos/Top 10 Plays of 2015.mp4")
    title = StringProperty("Top 10 Plays of 2015")

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(MainApp,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    pass

class OtherVideos(BoxLayout, EventDispatcher):
    root = MainApp
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OtherVideos,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.loadVideos()

    def loadVideos(self):
        con = MongoClient()
        db = con.nba
        vids = db.videos.find()

        vidnum = 1
        for filename in vids:
            myid = "vid" + str(vidnum)
            getfilename = filename['filename']

            button = Button(id=myid,
                          text=getfilename,
                          color=[0,0.7,1],
                          bold=1)

            button.bind(on_release=lambda x:(self.change_Title(getfilename), self.change_Vid(getfilename)))
            self.add_widget(button)
            vidnum += 1

    def change_Title(self, title):
        self.root.title = title

    def change_Vid(self, myfilename):
        con = MongoClient()
        db = con.nba
        vids = db.videos.find()

        for filename in vids:
            file = os.path.basename(filename['video_path'])
            if myfilename == filename['filename']:
                self.root.vid = filename['video_path']
                break
    pass
```

kivy

```
BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            Label:
                id: lblTitle
                text: root.title
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 40
                font_size: 25
                bold: 1
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgba: 1, 0, 0, 0.7
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
            VideoPlayer:
                id: activeVid
                source: root.vid
                state: 'play'
```

when I'm printing `root.title` it's changing its text but the label is not changing which it should because it's getting its text from that variable.

But when I'm putting the `change_title()` method in `__init__` of `OtherVideos` like this, the label is changing:

```
class OtherVideos(BoxLayout, EventDispatcher):
    root = MainApp
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OtherVideos,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.change_Title("my title")
```

This is already taking me days of work, anyone can help?

Answer (score 4):

There are several problems with your code:

1. Every widget inherits from `EventDispatcher`, so inheriting from it the second time is pointless.
2. This `root = MainApp` is not a reference to the `MainApp` (object), but to its class.
3. You don't need to specify a `StringProperty` to achieve your goal.

The easiest way to do this is to add a reference of the label you want to change in the function `change_Title`:

```
def change_Title(self, title):
    # self.root.title = title
    self.ids.my_label_to_change.text = title
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm getting 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'

Comment: @KPA Then you are trying to access an id which doesn't exist in the current scope.

Comment: I already have it as lblTitle, I don't know why its not being detected

Comment: @KPA Every id is limited to the scope in which it was defined. It is not global. If you want to use id of `lblTitle` in `OtherVideos` box layout, you need to link it there. Here is a basic example how to do this: https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html#referencing-widgets (if it is too basic, then search SO, I've been already answering to such questions)